# Linear programming: What is the set of gradients of the objective function for which a given extreme point of the feasible region is optimal?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-hulls

Consider the linear program,

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text { Maximize } & \mathbf{c}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{x} \\
\text { subject to } & A \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b} \\
\text { and } & \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}
\end{array}
$$

As illustrated in the simple 2-dimensional  picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), the set of gradients $c$ for which a given extreme point $X$ of the feasible region is an optimal solution seems to be everything "in between" the slopes of the two lines of the boundary which intersect at $X$ (i.e. the two constraints which hold with equality at $X$).

Extending the same logic, it is my understanding that for a general $n$-dimensional linear program, the set of gradients of the linear objective function $c$ for which a given extreme point $X$ of the feasible region is a solution, is the convex hull of the gradients $A$ of all the hyperplanes representing the constraints which hold with equality at $X$. Is this correct? Even if yes, we would need to do some kind of normalization of the gradients (say, normalize the coefficient of one of the variables to 1) to be able to take convex combinations. If we do that by normalizing the coefficient of one of the variables to 1, what do we do for constraints which do not contain that variable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_fan   "If polytope P is thought of as the feasible region of a linear program, the normal fan of P partitions the space of objective functions based on the solution set to the linear program defined by each. The linear program in which the goal is to maximize linear objective function w has solution set F if and only if w is in the relative interior of the cone CF."

Comment: By the way, this intuition is basically one step removed from the geometric / physical proof of strong duality and complementary slackness in linear programming. This is explained in Schrijver's book, see my comment here for a reference to the literature: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24892/intuitively-why-is-the-complementary-slackness-condition-true

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I spent a lot of time trying to understand dual spaces and normal fans. I went thru p 93 in the book too. But it seems I still can't visualize the characterization. $C_F$. How to visualize the relative interior of the cone $C_F$ in the dual space? I'm not very familiar with dual spaces and only just learning. Any references to a diagram would be much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe check out Fig 9.19 in "The Nature of Computation."

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm still not sure about the following detail. Suppose $b=0$. One  of the constraints is: $a_kx_k + \cdots + a_l x_l \leq 0$. We consider an extreme point $X$ where $x_k = \cdots = x_l=0,$ so $a_kx_k + \cdots + a_l x_l \leq 0$ holds with equality *as a consequence*. So should we disregard $a_kx_k + \cdots + a_l x_l \leq 0$ as one of the constraints which hold with equality at $X$? In other words, is it without loss to set the coeff of this constr to $0$ in the non-negative linear comb of gradients of constraints binding at $X$ which $c$ must equal?

Comment: If you take the polyhedron $x \leq 0$, then $0$ is a vertex. The normal fan at $x$ consists of all non-negative vectors $c$, and you need the constraint $x \leq 0$ to get that cone so you can't just ignore it. (Does this answer your question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is an extreme point of the feasible region, necessary and sufficient for $X$ to be an optimal solution is that there does not exist any vector $\bf v$ with ${\bf a}^T {\bf v} \le 0$ for all gradients $\bf a$ of
constraints which are equalities at $X$ and ${\bf c}^T {\bf v} > 0$.
Obviously there can't be such a $\bf v$ if $\bf c$ is a linear combination with nonnegative coefficients of those gradients $\bf a$, i.e. is a conical combination of those gradients.
Conversely, if $\bf c$ is not a conical combination of those gradients,
such a $\bf v$ exists by the Separation Theorem.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm still not sure about the following detail. Suppose $b=0$. One of the constraints is:
$a_{k} x_{k}+\cdots+a_{l} x_{l} \leq 0$. We consider an extreme point $X$ where $x_{k}=\cdots=x_{l}=0,$ so $a_{k} x_{k}+\cdots+a_{l} x_{l} \leq 0$ holds with equality as a consequence. So should we disregard $a_{k} x_{k}+\cdots+a_{l} x_{l} \leq 0$ as one of the constraints which hold with equality at $X$ ? In other words, is it without loss to set the coeff of this constr to 0 in the non-negative linear comb of gradients of constraints binding at $X$ which $c$ must equal?

Comment: In general you must include this constraint, unless it is a consequence of other constraints.

Comment: The constraint itself is not implied by other constraints. But if a subset of the $x_k \geq 0$ constraints *hold with equality*, then that constraint also holds with equality. So should that constraint be included in that case? I think yes. Let me know. Thanks so much again.

Comment: Yes, it should be included.